# How to prevent QAbstractScrollArea / QTableView from horizontal scrolling?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qscrollarea

I have a QTableView and some content in it. I want a behavior like `horizontalHeader() -> setResizeMode( ResizeToContent )` but it must not create horizontal scrollbars - I mean the viewport must not be wider than the table.

Even with creating a new QHeaderView it's not so easy, since there are only a few virtual methods.

[image: drawing to visualize the problem]

Thanks in advance,

Charly

PS: I have a custom item delegate, which shortens the long texts with "...". It returns as sizeHint() the full size, but when the paint() method receives a smaller size (e.g. simulated with resizeMode() == Qt::Interactive) it crops the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**New Answer**

You need to set the stretch on individual sections, I've created a simple test app:

[image: Screen shot of test]

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStandardItemModel mdl(3, 3); // rows, cols
    mdl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "Name" << "Size" << "Date");
    mdl.setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem("Short name"));
    mdl.setItem(0, 1, new QStandardItem("25kb"));
    mdl.setItem(0, 2, new QStandardItem("2011/07/05"));
    mdl.setItem(1, 0, new QStandardItem("This is a long name"));
    mdl.setItem(1, 1, new QStandardItem("25kb"));
    mdl.setItem(1, 2, new QStandardItem("2011/07/05"));
    mdl.setItem(2, 0, new QStandardItem("This is a long long long long name"));
    mdl.setItem(2, 1, new QStandardItem("25kb"));
    mdl.setItem(2, 2, new QStandardItem("2011/07/05"));


    QTableView view;
    view.setModel(&mdl);
    QHeaderView* hdr = view.horizontalHeader();
    hdr->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);
    hdr->setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
    hdr->setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += core gui
SOURCES=test.cpp
```

**Notice**: It's important that `void QHeaderView::setResizeMode(int, ResizeMode)` is called when when this logical index exists, that is, when a model which defines these columns is attached to the view.

---

**Old Answer**

QAbstractScrollArea has the [horizontalScrollBarPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) property which can have the option `ScrollBarAlwaysOff`.

Try something like:

```
QAbstractScrollArea* scrollArea = // ???
scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

---

Comment: Using `ScrollBarAlwaysOff` has a different effect. It just hides the scrollbar, but has no influence on the size of the column - or at least does not solve the problem.

Comment: What about also setting the properties `resizeMode` to `ResizeToContent` and `stretchLastSection` to `true`? You could add a sketch/drawing/mockup to your post to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, I will prepare a drawing. `ResizeToContent` and `strechLastSection(true)` doesn't help...

Comment: The test-app works fine, my 'real app' doesn't work... but this is what I can figure out for myself. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: it wasn't working because I set the resize mode at a time, where no model was attached - thus the table has zero columns and this data got lost. I added this point to your answer...